# Meteor.users.allow for Autoform

Tags: meteor, crud, meteor-autoform, meteor-useraccounts

my first time playing with Meteor, and this question probably comes from my lack of understanding the allow/deny concept of Collections.

I have a page that is accessible by the logged in admin, which allows the admin to modify existing users.

To allow use of autoform to edit existing users, I roughly followed the steps listed in both these websites (except for the "allow"/"deny" part)
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers
http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2015/05/25/user-profile-edit-with-autoform-and-simpleschema-in-meteor-js/

I end up having a page with a table of users. **Each row** has an edit button which leads to an Edit autoform, using the following code:

```
{{#afModal class="btn btn-primary" collection="Meteor.users" operation="update" doc=_id}}
    Edit
{{/afModal}}
```

This successfully opens an edit form, I change some user details, and i click "update", I get a Meteor 403 Access denied error.

This error I somehow solved it by inserting this code:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true
});
```

My question is, why do i need to perform this "allow" explicitly for "users", as I have another similar CRUD page setup for a custom collection called "battleships", which worked well with autoform without having to specify these "allow" rules?

Note also I have removed autopublish and insccure packages.

Answer (score 1):

Might have answered my own question here, my custom collections also have allow and deny rules set up, my mistake that i had forgotten.

Also referred to 
[Insert using Autoform with insecure removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281645/insert-using-autoform-with-insecure-removed)